# Creating datatables from Javascript source

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I am trying to build a datatable (1.10.7) based on an input of a javascript var filled with JSON data.  While I've successfully used datatables with ajax sources, I've never attempted to just provide my own variable, but I need to in this case.

Here's my variable:

```
json = [
 {"dateReceived":"2015-01-01","designCustomer":"MULTITEST 1","designCustomerLocation":"SUNNYVALE, CA"},
 {"dateReceived":"2016-04-05","designCustomer":"MULTITEST 2","designCustomerLocation":"SUNNYVALE, CA"},
 {"dateReceived":"1982-04-18","designCustomer":"MULTITEST 3","designCustomerLocation":"SUNNYVALE, CA"}
 ]
```

According to [DataTables' page on Javascript-Sourced Data](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html),

```
This is achieved using the dataDT option in the initialisation object, passing in an array of data to be used (like all other DataTables handled data, this can be arrays or objects using the columns.dataDT option).
```

I'm confused by the differences in their test string, and in mine:

```
var dataSet = [
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 6','Win 98+','6','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 7','Win XP SP2+','7','A']
```

Namely, their test variable doesn't contain `field names`, while mine does.

Here is the code that I've written to try and parse my variable, `json`:

```
var table = $('#ltc-table').DataTable( {    
    "data" : json,        
    "columns" : [
      { "title" : "designCustomer" },
      { "title" : "designCutomerLocation" },
      { "title" : "dateReceived" },
  ],
  "lengthMenu": [ 25, 50, 101 ],
  "oLanguage": {
  "sSearch": "Filter Results: "
  }
});
```

It seems, based on the page I linked above, that I'm doing this correctly, but I'm getting errors instead:

```
Uncaught Error: DataTables warning: table id=ltc-table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0.
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use [objects as data source](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) instead of arrays, you need to *bind* the columns using the `columns.data` options:

```
json = [
 {"dateReceived":"2015-01-01","designCustomer":"MULTITEST 1","designCustomerLocation":"SUNNYVALE, CA"},
 {"dateReceived":"2016-04-05","designCustomer":"MULTITEST 2","designCustomerLocation":"SUNNYVALE, CA"},
 {"dateReceived":"1982-04-18","designCustomer":"MULTITEST 3","designCustomerLocation":"SUNNYVALE, CA"}
];

var table = $('#ltc-table').DataTable( {    
    "data" : json,        
    "columns" : [
      { "data" : "designCustomer" },
      { "data" : "designCustomerLocation" },
      { "data" : "dateReceived" }
  ],
  "lengthMenu": [ 25, 50, 101 ],
  "oLanguage": {
  "sSearch": "Filter Results: "
  }
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/56dkaL7v/)

Comment: Yeah this is totally accurate... your fiddle works perfectly.  I wonder why I'm still getting errors even after changing `title` to `data`.  Now I'm getting `Uncaught Error: DataTables warning: table id=ltc-table - Requested unknown parameter 'designCustomer' for row 0.` , but right above it in my `console.log` I clearly see `"designCustomer":"MULTITEST 1",`

Comment: Probably the spelling. Check your spelling in the `columns.data` matches the fields names in the json.

Comment: They match perfectly.

Comment: I don't understand this.  If I create a variable on the same page : `json = [{"dateReceived":"2015-01-01","designCustomer":"MULTITEST 1"` etc..., it works, but it doesn't work if I pass `json` from another page - even though `console.log(json)` reads the EXACT same text as I'm putting into the variable on this second page. Arrghhhh